# Command to compile using libboost_python on ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost-python

I am trying to compile my code using libboost library, by putting `#include <boost/python.hpp>` in my C++ code. Could somebody please help me the right command to run this, especially to include and link the library. I'm pretty basic in this.

The command used(but not working):

`g++ try.cpp -L /usr/lib/libboost_python.so -o try`

EDIT:

The tested code:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{

    std::cout << "Yes, it works :-)" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Error messages:

```
from try.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/python/enum.hpp:31: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/boost/python/enum.hpp:32: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/boost/python/enum.hpp:33: error: ‘PyObject’ has not been declared
/usr/include/boost/python/enum.hpp:52: error: expected constructor, destructor, or     type conversion before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/boost/python/enum.hpp:67: error: ‘void*       boost::python::enum_<T>::convertible_from_python’ is not a static member of ‘struct     boost::python::enum_<T>’
/usr/include/boost/python/enum.hpp:67: error: template definition of non-template ‘    void* boost::python::enum_<T>::convertible_from_python’
/usr/include/boost/python/enum.hpp:67: error: ‘PyObject’ was not declared in this     scope
/usr/include/boost/python/enum.hpp:67: error: ‘obj’ was not declared in this scope
    /usr/include/boost/python/enum.hpp:80: error: variable or field ‘construct’     declared void 
/usr/include/boost/python/enum.hpp:80: error: ‘PyObject’ was not declared in this     scope
/usr/include/boost/python/enum.hpp:80: error: ‘obj’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/boost/python/enum.hpp:80: error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/boost/python/enum.hpp:80: error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope
```

Another thing is that when I compile `g++ -Wall thread_one.cpp -o thread_one -lboost_thread`, that works in order to use boost_thread library.

Comment: Could it be you are missing Python? The error is not a linker error but a C++ error.

Comment: What are your compiler and boost versions?

Comment: @Kerrrk: The compiler is g++ and boost version is 1.40.0

Comment: @pmr: It's not a C++ error I would say, because whenever I comment the boost_python header, the code compiled successfully.

Comment: @Shah Which makes it obvious that this is a compiler error and not a linker error. It seems some part of your python/boost configuration is broken.

Comment: @pmr: Any idea on how I should fix it?

Comment: @pmr: But, I still think that something is missing in the command, as it also need `-I` something normally.

Comment: @Shah: Maybe you need a newer compiler? This works for me with GCC 4.7.0 and Boost 1.4.9, though it also fails with an older Boost version.

Comment: @KerrekSB: But, GCC 4.4.3 is the latest on ubuntu 10.04 LTS..It's not really recommended to upgrade it, or else I also need to upgrade my ubuntu latest version, which I don't want. Any other alternatives?

Comment: I'm still thinking that there's a way out to solve it by referring/linking to the appropriate place, but I don't know much about those low level stuff.

Comment: @Kerrek: Another thing is that when I compile `g++ -Wall thread_one.cpp -o thread_one -lboost_thread`, that works in order to use boost_thread library. It means the libboost is still functioning and I also tried to compile python code(pure python), it also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it is working. The command used is as below:

`g++ -I/usr/include/python2.6 try.cpp -o try -lboost_python -lpython2.6`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
g++ try.cpp -o try -lboost_python
```

It'd be good style to also add `-W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your compiler invocation (so that your next SO question can be more specific :-)). Also, `-O2` or `-O3` for optimization is probably a very good idea, especially with Boost. Finally, splitting the building up into separate stages makes recompiling faster when you have multiple files:

```
g++ -c -o try.o try.cpp -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2
g++ -o try try.o -s -lboost_python
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I'm getting a very long error message with this command.

Comment: Also, with the updated command, I'm getting some error messages.

Comment: @Shah: Where is your boost installation? It's entirely possible that the error has nothing to do with linking against Boost, but simply with writing correct C++ code.

Comment: The libboost_python is located in /usr/lib/ directory.

Comment: @Shah: And the header files? Anyway, your problem is almost definitely not with Boost.

Comment: I don't think it's about C++ code error because I'm just using <boost/python.hpp> and #include <iostream> along with "hello world" messages output. It's about linking against the library is probably wrong.

Comment: Post your actual error (edit it into your post). It's impossible to guess this, especially if you're getting "very long error messages".

Comment: Yes, I've included it as above.